# Code that generates magento module structure

Tags: php, magento

Can anyone indicate me an php code that generates the magento module structure, in 2012 I found this kind of code but now I was not able to remember where I found it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html

Comment: You better be asking this in Magento forums or here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I found it: http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-createn-custom-magento-module-step-by-step-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-createn-custom-magento-module-step-by-step-tutorial/
```

for someone this could be helpfull..